# RecyclerView как правильно подсветить выделенный элемент?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Я изучаю RecyclerView  в нашем проекте. И постоянно возникают непонимания. Вот и сейчас. У меня есть список в котором нужно подсвечивать активный елемент. при нажатии на другой, подсвечивается он а подсветка предыдущего пропадает. Я это реализовал сейчас так

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView userAvatar;
        public ImageView choice;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            userAvatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.userAvatar);
            choice = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.choce);

            Observer.getInstance().register(this);

            userAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    userAvatar.setPressed(true);
                    Observer.getInstance().send(MessageType.USER_LIST_ADAPTER_UNMARK, Integer.valueOf(getPosition()));

                    choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

        @Subscribe(MessageType.USER_LIST_ADAPTER_UNMARK)
        public void unmarkLogo(Integer indexOfSelected){
            if(getPosition() == indexOfSelected){
                return;
            }

            choice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Но меня смущает моя реализация. Я думаю можно это сделать проще или по-другому. Может ктото сталкивался такой задачей?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Те. нужен аналог single choice ListView - `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`?

Answer (score 6):

Самый простой способ это создать XML файл в папке drawable.

Назовем его bg.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/color2" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/color1" />
</selector>
```

А потом установить background основному элементу в XML, который вы используете в onCreateViewHolder() :

```
android:background="@drawable/bg"
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color1">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="color2">#CCCCCC</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: А потом установить background основному элементу в XML когда потом? ответ вообще не по вопросу

Comment: 1, После создания  XML файла в папке drawable. 2, Установка созданого drawable (bx.xml) как background, приведет к тому, что при нажатии фон будет менять цвет.

Comment: мне нужно немного другое. фон должен остаться. далее при нажатии на новый элемент фон должен перейти на него а на старом пропасть. как установить не проблема, а вот как снять выдиление с остальных

Answer (score 2):

Да нормальная реализация. Обычно делается примерно так.

- В адаптере хранится ID, либо позиция активного элемента списка.
- В *onBindViewHolder()* элемент биндится в зависимости от статуса: если активен - один вариант, если нет - другой. Если `choice` - это у вас бэкраунд элемента, то так лучше не делать. Возьмите лучше селектор, как вам предложили в другом ответе, и поставьте его на элемент атрибутом *android:bacgrkound* и затем здесь просто ставьте `setSelected()`, либо `setActivated()`
- При нажатии на элемент в списке, вызывается метод, меняющий выделенный элемент и вызывающий *notifyItemChanged()* для старой позиции и для новой, либо *notifyDataSetChanged()*. *View.OnClickListener* можно установить не на ViewHolder, а в активности, во вложенном отнаследованном от адаптера классе. Т. е. там, где есть доступ к самому RecyclerView.

Примеры похожих реализаций:

- [SingleActivatedList](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/SingleActivatedList)
- [DynamicRecyclerView](https://github.com/ismoli/DynamicRecyclerView)
- [RecyclerView Part 2: Choice Modes](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/)

Comment: Обычно это делается через селекторы, как в первом ответе. Что то как то UI в коде это .. не нужен он там совсем, в общем .. Есть специальные инструменты , селекторы - повесил на бэкграунд и забыл. Незачем придумывать себе приключений без необходимости. Я вот заметил, что такая упертость тащить UI в код наблюдается в основном у СИшников - сейчас другие как бы тренды в программировании - UI сам по себе, логика сама, все аккуратно и на своем месте. Такое мое мнение.

Comment: @pavlofff, Да, можно навесить бэкграунд  с селектором и в onBindViewHolder() ставить у вьюхи checked() / activated(). Но вы не поняли основной проблемы, тут не об этом.

Comment: ...или я неправильно понял :) Но в RecyclerView смысл в том, что вьюхи используются повторно, поэтому инфу о выделенном элементе нужно хранить где-нибудь снаружи, иначе вся эта инфа пропадет при скролле и переиспользовании вьюхи.

Comment: Да не, это я поторопился, в вопросе нужен аналог SingleChoice ListView для RecyclerView. Извините за беспокойство.